# Application Error: Potocol not supported when running phone gap on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I've created a very basic project on Android using Eclipse with PhoneGap following the Getting Started guide (http://phonegap.com/start#android). When I run my app, I get the following error message:

"Application error"
"The protocol is not supported. (e:///android_asset/www/index.html)"

Any idea why is that error raising? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats because it will be

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

correct that in your Home.java

Comment: sorry... where is located that file? I can't find it into my project, thanks